# Can I get a working curl command to remove a system from RHEL subscription?

Tags: api, redhat, rhel

I want to automate the addition and removal of VMs from the RHEL Subscription. I want to use a curl command if possible and keep it simple.

I tried executing curl commands on the api.access.redhat.com/management/v1/subscriptions endpoints but it is giving errors like "Authentication parameters missing".

Below is an example command I am using:

```
curl -X GET -s -k -u username:Password "https://api.access.redhat.com/management/v1/subscriptions" -H "accept: application/json"
```

Expected to see the list of Subscribed systems but getting the "Authentication parameters missing" message.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all the subscriptions you have, run the following command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" "https://api.access.redhat.com/management/v1/subscriptions"
```

You can retrieve the **access_token** variable by running the following command:

```
curl https://sso.redhat.com/auth/realms/redhat-external/protocol/openid-connect/token -d grant_type=refresh_token -d client_id=rhsm-api -d refresh_token=$offline_token
```

The **offline_token**, instead, has to be generated from the [API Tokens Page](https://access.redhat.com/management/api).

Check [this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3626371) article for further details.